# Is randomize an inbuilt function in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

```
class sample;
  randc bit[2:0]count;
endclass

module top;
  sample sample_test;
  initial begin
    sample_inst=new();
    repeat(20) begin
      sample_inst.randomize();
      sample.print();// this is assumed to be written in class
    end
  end
endmodule
```

I understood what `rand` and `randc` are, but I don't understand how we are able to use `randomize()` without writing a function in SystemVerilog class. I assume it is an inbuilt function. I have seen many codes online which don't have `randomize` function written in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `randomize` is a built-in function, as defined in the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18.6.1 *Randomize()*:

> Variables in an object are randomized using the randomize() class
> method. Every class has a built-in randomize() virtual method,
> declared as follows:

```
virtual function int randomize();
```

This means that all the code examples you see online do not declare a `randomize` function.

Free copies of the [IEEE Std](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/system-verilog/info) are available.  This should be your first source for all information.